# Could not initialize GLX Ubuntu Server

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, google-cloud-platform, genymotion

I'm using Google Cloud server with a GPU and trying to run Android emulator on it. Vncserver is running on server and Im connecting by VNC Viewer.
But everytime I try to run Android emulator or Genymotion it fails?

> Could not initialize GLX
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If so, would you post an answer for the benefit of the community? Thank you

Comment: No I couldn't..

Answer (score 0):

It does not sound to me like you have setup your OpenGL ES / GLES environment on the server ?

You can also make sure to check from the emulator what acceleration features are available to it.

```
emulator -accel-check
```

If you just want to continue without using OpenGL/Acceleration you can give it the parameter mode.

```
-gpu off
```

I highly recommend you take a look at Google Android Developer documentation on Emulator acceleration.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

Also depending on your GPU type, let's assume it's NVIDIA Tesla. Then referring to the Google Cloud platform installation guide on GPUs this should help you out.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#install-gpu-driver

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but Nvidia drivers are installed
-accel-check output is:
accel:
0
KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
accel

Comment: @EmreTekince what does "glxinfo" output ? I still don't think you have it setup properly. Also are you running X under Vnc ? (And are you using Virtual OpenGL for VNC?)

Comment: it outputs: name of display: :1 Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig. I'm not sure VirtualGL or X running

Comment: @EmreTekince if you use x11vnc I know that one supports native OpenGL via VNC. If you're using some other vnc server your properly need to use VirtualGL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Genymotion on Google Cloud Platform, then [Genymotion Cloud PaaS](https://www.genymotion.com/cloud-paas/) is probably a better option.